# Changing Visibility of a button inside the component dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using [React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) but I guess You don't really need to have a prior knowledge about it.

So I have a `header Component` which looks like this

```
const Header = (props) => {
  return (
  <View style={headerContainer}>
    <View> 
     <Button onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')} 
      title="Go Back"/> 
    </View>
    <Text style={header}> Knicx   
     <Text style={headerSecondary}> Crypto Ticker </Text> 
     </Text>
  </View>
  )
}
```

Now, In the above notice the button, Which I am currently showing on all the pages

```
 <Button onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')} 
          title="Go Back"/>
```

But I don't want it to be there on some specific pages, like HomeScreen to say the least.

Now, One solution is to remove the `<Header />` component in my homepage, Copy the above code snippet, past it in my HomeScreen and remove the  Component ( sort of like hardcoding ) or two create two Header component, one with button and one without button

**[Question:]** But I was thinking if we could toggle the visibility of button dynamically or stack it on the top of `<Header />` ? Can someone please tell me how can we do it? (No, We can set the opacity of the button to zero and change it whenever we need it)

**[Update:]** We can use redux to manage/pass the state but the problem is that in **React-native** we do not have `display: none` and I don't want to change use the `opacity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send `showHomeButton: boolean` as a prop to header

```
const Header = props => (
    <View style={headerContainer}>
        {this.props.showHomeButton && (
            <View>
                <Button onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')} title="Go Back" />
            </View>
        )}
        <Text style={header}>
            {' '}
                Knicx
            <Text style={headerSecondary}> Crypto Ticker </Text>
        </Text>
    </View>
);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - passing props and conditional rendering is the react mindset after all.